# Why aren't the Community user's accounts linked?

Tags: support, profile-page, user-accounts, community-user

When visiting the Community user's profile on any site, it doesn't have any other linked accounts. This makes navigating to Community's other profiles a bit difficult.

It looks like each profile is a separate user, and that's why they can't really be connected. Is that true? If so, what was the reason behind this decision?

Comment: @bobble Doesn't really answer the last question but I'm satisfied.

Comment: animuson's answer explains the technical reason for this.